# Float text right of div/image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to float the lorem ipsum sample text to the right of the image and div container. I have set the float to right with no luck as it still sits under the image.

[What it needs to look like](http://postimg.org/image/wzsy7b9dr/)

Thanks in advance.

```css
#outer {
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: outset;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: rgb(127, 127, 255);
  padding: 5px;
}
#inner {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  border-style: outset;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: rgb(191, 233, 191);
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#image {
  clear: both;
}
#paragraph {
  float: right;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Div Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type "text/css" href="chandra.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="outer">



    <h1> The Chandra space-based X-Ray Observatory</h1>

    <div id="inner">
      <a href="http://science.nasa.gov/astrophysics/focus-areas/black-holes/">Nearby black hole</a>
      <br>
      <a href="http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/chandra/news/07-139.html" />'Death Star' Galaxy Black Hole</a>
      <br>
      <a href="http://www.nasa.gov/content/black-holes-have-simple-feeding-habits/">Black Holes feeding</a>
      <br>
      <a href="https://www.nasa.gov/jpl/nustar/tale-of-two-black-holes/">Two Black Holes</a>
      </br>
    </div>

    <div id="image">
      <img src="binary.jpg" alt="Binary" style="width:226px;height:170px;">
    </div>


    <div id="paragraph">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </br>
        </br>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </br>
        </br>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/94wx7wcb/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
#outer {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: rgb(127, 127, 255);
    padding: 5px;
}
#inner {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: rgb(191, 233, 191);
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    clear: both;
    width: 200px;
}
#image {
    //clear: both;
    float:left;
}
#paragraph {
    //float: right;
    margin: 25px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/enLkzkkk/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:)

```
<head>
    <title>Div Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type "text/css" href="chandra.css" />
</head>
<style>
    #inner {
        width: 23%;
        height: auto;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        float: left;
    }

    #paragraph {
        width: 77%;
        height: auto;
        float: right;
    }

    #image {
        width: 23%;
        height: auto;
        position: static;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <h1> The Chandra space-based X-Ray Observatory</h1>
    <div id="inner">
        <a href="http://science.nasa.gov/astrophysics/focus-areas/black-holes/">Nearby black hole</a>
        <br>
        <a href="http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/chandra/news/07-139.html" />'Death Star' Galaxy Black Hole</a>
        <br>
        <a href="http://www.nasa.gov/content/black-holes-have-simple-feeding-habits/">Black Holes feeding</a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.nasa.gov/jpl/nustar/tale-of-two-black-holes/">Two Black Holes</a>
        </br>
    </div>
    <div id="paragraph">
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </br>
            </br>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </br>
            </br>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="image">
        <img src="binary.jpg" alt="Binary" style="width:226px;height:170px;">
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```